# jQuery Ajax call with async returns null responseXML

Tags: jquery

I have simple JavaScript code that is using the Ajax API for fetching a XML from the server.

```
function loadXML(path, node) {
    var response_obj = "";
    /* Fire Ajax request and get the XML */
    var request_obj = "";
    $.ajax({
        async: true,
        type: "GET",
        url: path,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(XMLObj, status, resquestObj) {
            response_obj = XMLObj;
            request_obj = requestObj;
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("Unable to fire AJAX request");
        }
    });
    alert(response_obj); //<-- This is NULL if async=true
   /* More logic to follow which will use response_obj (XML)
      and render it in the 'node' argument passed. */
}
```

Where, the path corresponds to a *valid* XML (tested using [W3C validator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W3C_Markup_Validation_Service)) and the node points to a DIV element on the HTML page where the response has to be parsed and appended.

What I need is that the Ajax call should return me the `responseXML` object which I will parse and render. For that, I am assigning the response XML to a local variable (local to this function's scope) and then would use it (currently I just send it to alert).

Now, the problem is that when I use this function with `async` set to `false`, the `alert` call successfully returns `[object XMLDocument]`. But as soon as I change `async` to `true`, `null` is printed by `alert`.

What I understand is that when `async:true`, the last `alert` is called even before the XML is returned by the Ajax call. Similarly, when `async:false`, this is a serialized call and when control reaches the last `alert` call, the XML has already arrived.

What should I do so that:

1. I have the response Object (and
   request object) as returned by the Ajax
   call in the local variables so that
   I can use them. I understand that
   the call back function, if passed to
   `success`, would have three
   parameters - but, I don't know how
   to return from that call back
   function into my `loadXML` function.
2. That I don't have to convert the Ajax call into sync because this is just one of the functions that I am firing - there are many other Ajax calls which too are to be issued.
3. Am I correct in my assumption that `async:false` is serialized in this function whereas `async:true` is not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, what you have mentioned about `async:true` is correct. So it's natural that `alert()` will fail if async is true and if async is false it will work.

You should put the `alert()` in the success callback.

Or you can also make a function say `ajaxSuccess` and call it in success `Callback()`.
Put the `alert()` in that `ajaxSuccess` function.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Actually, which ever function gets the XML, also needs the HTML 'node' - so, my problem is what should I do so that the callback has the node also. (I apologize in case this was not implicit in the question text). Thanks anyways, for confirming my understanding.