# Trying to fetch data from database using Json and display it in handsontable. The table is not displaying the data correctly

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, razor, handsontable

````
        This is the code for fetching the data from database using Json and displaying it in handsontable. I checked in console and it shows the data I am getting from database but somehow that data is not being displayed in handsontable.
        ```


<div id="example"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">          
    const container = document.getElementById('example');
    var hot = new Handsontable(container, {
    //  data: getData(),               
        rowHeaders: true,
        colHeaders: true,                
        licenseKey: 'non-commercial-and-evaluation',
        colHeaders: true
        });               

    $(document).ready(function () {  
                var result = null;
                $.ajax({
                        url: 'someurl',
                        type: 'post',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        async: false,
                        success: function (res) {
                        result = res;                             
                        },
                        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown);                            
                            }
                        });
              console.log(result);
              var resultdata = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));
              hot.loadData(resultdata);
    });
    </script>
````

*This is the Code from controller that is fetching the data from the database and returning it. I don't know if I am returning right type of data or if the data returned needs to be serialized. Can anyone help me with this? I will really appreciate any help from anyone*

```
     public class SupplierTypeController : BaseController
        {
            [HttpGet]
            public JsonResult Index()
            {
          IEnumerable<SupplierTypeDto> supplierType = new List<SupplierTypeDto>();
                var apiResponse = Post<List<SupplierTypeDto>>("api/SupplierType/SuppliersType", null);

                if (apiResponse != null)
                {
                    if (apiResponse.Success)
                    {
                        supplierType = apiResponse.Data;

                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    ShowErrorMesage(ResponseMessages.API_NoResponse);
                }

                return Json(supplierType,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }

          }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery Ajax call with async returns null responseXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3180166/jquery-ajax-call-with-async-returns-null-responsexml)

Comment: No it doesn't help me as I am successfully fetching the data using ajax but the problem is displaying that data in handsontable.

Comment: You have exactly the same problem. You make an async call and you expect your your code works like sync. `var resultdata = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));
          hot.loadData(resultdata);` move these lines into `success` method.

Comment: @Eldar I have tried everything but so far I am stuck at showing data in handsontable I have checked it in console the data is being fetched from data base and passed to handsontable. Here is the data that is passed

Comment: You should also add how you serialize your data at back end and what you retrieve from database.

Comment: @Eldar I found the issue and now trying to fix it. The code written in controller is not returning the right type of data. I think I need to serialize the data coming from database. Can u please check my code and tell me what is to be fixed there. I have added the code of controller up with the code added earlier. Kindly check it out.

Comment: Your backend code seems ok. You need to populate data on success method.

Comment: @Eldar I did that as well but it didn't work. Is it possible that the data I get is an HTTPResponseMessage so that can cause a problem in data not being loaded in the table. I don't know how to share the screenshot of the data in the console that is being returned for the table.